# ASP.NET - Input string was not in a correct format while using WebClient DownloadString()

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, webclient

I have simple ASP.NET app for currency convert. When I try it on localhost everything works fine. However when app is running ony hosting WebClient's DownloadString() method throws Input string was not in a correct format exception.

My code:

```
string s =
        wc.DownloadString(
        "http://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni_trhy/devizovy_trh/kurzy_devizoveho_trhu/denni_kurz.txt");
```

What could be wrong? It is possible that hosting I use has some limitation?

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

It looks like the problem is not in DownloadString(). After that I have code to substring desired exchange rates

```
s = s.Replace(',', '.');

        string eur = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("EUR") + 4);
        rateEUR = Convert.ToDouble(euro.Substring(0, 6));
```

But why would this work locally and not on hosting?

Well the problem is solved. It was problem with different cultures. I thought replacing , with . was sufficient but apparently not.

```
string euro = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("EUR") + 4);        
        rateEUR = Convert.ToDouble(euro.Substring(0, 6), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Do you need to provide authentication credentials (username/password)?

Comment: Do you have to go through a proxy?

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=VS.100).aspx for possible cause

Comment: @Zirkonix The code works, nothing wrong with the string

Comment: @parad1s3 probably worth showing more of your code